Modifyng SQL data in MySQL UDFs
I want to define a user defined function in MySQL that writes some data to the database.
So I wrote:
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION BlockAsset(
    userId int
) 
    RETURNS int 
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE balance int;
    SET balance = (
        SELECT ...
    );
    IF balance = 0 THEN
        RETURN -1;
    END IF;
    UPDATE ...; 
    RETURN 1;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;

But I faced with this error:
#1418 - This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

I can't add DETERMINISTIC because its result is depends on the database in addition to input value.
If I add NO SQL then I cannot use SQL phrases in it.
If I add READS SQL DATA then I cannot use UPDATE SQL command in it.
What can I do?
P.S: ChatGPT proposed using this command as the error message had told before:
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;

My problem solved with this command, but MySQL says that this command will be deprecated soon. I feel MySQL planned a suitable use for using commands that want to write data in UDFs.

CREATE FUNCTION is meant for SQL that queries/returns data without introducing any side-effects. For DML you want CREATE PROCEDURE.

So why we can use MODIFIES SQL DATA in it?

The MODIFIED SQL DATA thing was a mistake from before MySQL 5.5 that we're stuck with today. (Oh, and aFUNCTION can mutate TEMPORARY tables too - but my impression is that you should only do that when it's incidental to the FUNCTION's main purpose (e.g. eliminating unwanted data from an intermediate resultset).

its result is depends on the database in addition to input value You'd use NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA. ChatGPT proposed using this command as the error message had told before Ignore this advice.
